# Want to do something to view in item that got clicked in list view

Tags: java, android, listview, layout

I have two buttons  in each item that are set to invisible. I want, that when the user clicks on an item, the buttons only in that item turn to visible.

Im using a custom adapter for my list view...

```
public class LocationAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String [] n;
    Context context;
    String[] a;
    int bint = View.INVISIBLE;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public LocationAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] names, String[] addresses, int bint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.bint = bint;
        n=names;
        context=mainActivity;
        a=addresses;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return n.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView name;
        TextView address;
        Button b1;
        Button b2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout2, null);
        holder.name =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
        holder.address =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextAddress);
        holder.b1 = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Edit);
        holder.b2 = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        holder.b1.setVisibility(bint);
        holder.b2.setVisibility(bint);
        holder.name.setText(n[position]);
        holder.address.setText(a[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+n[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please give me ideas on how i need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` and change the visibility of the `Buttons` inside `onItemClick()`.

Also note that your current implementation of `LocationAdapter` does not check `if(convertView == null)` and it does not set the `ViewHoler` as the tag of the row `View`.

Comment: but how to i get a reference to a button inside an item, and additionally, how do i get the item that was clicked? please expound.

Comment: One way to get a reference to the `Button` would be using `findViewById()`. `onItemClick()` gives you the`View` of the row that was clicked. If the item is invisible and you want to respond to its click event you need to set an `OnClickListener()` on it (I do not think this is great UX since users cannot see the `Button` is there)

Comment: no i think you got what i was saying wrong-i have an invisible edit and delete button and when the user clicks the list item they appear for the user to interact with

Comment: When the user clicks on a row item delete and edit appear so the user can interact with them, right?

Comment: correct thats it but they arent clicking on the invisible buttons bc i will disable them unless they are visible

Comment: You might want to have a [contextual menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) for this case, but you would need to have an `onItemClickListener()`  to detect when the user taps on a row item. Then you need to also have `OnClickListeners` on the edit and delete buttons. You can set these listeners inside your adapter like you are doing now, but instead of setting it on the row view do it on the delete and edit `Buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

you only can set onclicklistener for view objects and its childs....so either you implementate your own API where you have a method that does the same as the standard onclicklistener but you can set it on every object that you want...would be very interesting imho...

or you use views like textviews etc and then set an onclicklistener on them!!!

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can try 
Add onclicklsitener to buttom instead of entire view. Inside buttons xml to which you want apply click listener add following two lines

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

now apply listener to button as follows

```
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
              //set visibility of items here
              holder.buttonedit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              holder.buttonedit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }
      });
```

Inside getview method declare holder final

```
final Holder holder=new Holder();
```

and you are done