# How to know which button in which item was clicked

Tags: android, layout

I have a delete button in each item in a listview that gives the user a chance to delete an item they created. I need to know though which button was clicked in which item- how do i get the item that a user clicked a button in? (i use a custom adapter)?Thanks

Comment: I answer to this question on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805311/want-to-do-something-to-view-in-item-that-got-clicked-in-list-view#comment47738909_29805378) comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the cleanest method but you can set your button onclick listener in your customadapter getview method

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ...

    Button btnDelete= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

       btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //execute your codes here

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a tag on the item. You can use an identifier of the tag (even an iterated value) to identify it

Comment: When he sets the `OnClickListener` on the `Buttons`, `onClick()` gets passed the view that was clicked. The `View` has the id of the `Button` that has clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTag(Object tag)` to set the item as tag of the button when you create each cell of the listview. And when the button got clicked use `getTag ()` to get the object (you need to cast it to your item type).

Then you can do whatever you want with your item.

Comment: can you explain a liitle more- also getTag returns what?

Comment: getTag returns object, check API docs. Genevieve's solution could be a good way to do this. You do not have to use tag.